# How to refresh listbox

Tags: ms-access, vba, listbox, refresh

What's the best way to refresh a list box in MS Access?  The way I have tried it doesn't seem to work :-/

This is my current method (onClick event of a button on the same form):

```
Me.orders.Requery
```

I have also tried

```
orders.Requery
```

and

```
Forms!currentOrders.orders.Requery
```

but none of them seem to refresh the list box's contents - I see no new items, even though I *know* that there are some.  Closing off the form, and then re-opening it does show the new items, however.

Comment: Where are you calling this? Can you post the code where you are calling this.

Comment: I'm calling it in the `onClick` event of a button on the same form - it's the only code for that button (basically, just a refresh button).

Comment: Is the listbox named "Orders" or "CurrentOrders"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try and requery the form first and then requery the listbox

Comment: That would seem to indicate that the listbox was showing data from the form you were editing, a detail that would have been helpful in your original question.

Comment: Requerying the form isn't necessary so something is still wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a temporary textbox, then your listbox will refresh automatically.
The following solution worked for me. (I don't know why, but using direct value from searchbox didn't work for me.) i have used no button. For instant search:

1. a textbox where you actually type. its name "Finder"
2. a textbox where you save the searching string temporarily. its name "Search".
3. a listbox where you show result. its name "lstResults"

(NB: also to mention, the query, uses the textbox named "Search"; which is our temporary textbox.)

code:

```
Private Sub Finder_Change()     ' "on change" event of "Finder" box
    Me.search = Me.Finder.Text  ' save the typed text in another textbox and use from there for query (otherwise it might not work)
    Me.lstResults.Requery       ' update listbox "lstResults" on any change
End Sub
```

[image: form view]

[image: vba code]
[image: query]

Answer (score 0):

I am still learning how to use access and I had the same problem.  Because my form is complex, it was far too cumbersome to create a duplicate textbox for each of the 12 search criteria on my form (like the example above).  My solution was eventually to requery followed by a form refresh and it worked.

```
me.lst_SearchResult.Requery
me.Refresh
```

Don't ask me why a function specifically written for the purpose doesn't work as it should, but my solution seems to work on every one of my forms linked to a query.  So I am happy.  I hope it works for you too.